# check time for time difference in 24hr

Tags: php, datetime

In php i get the variable $date_time in this format -- `11-01-2010 20:48:25` . This time is GMT time. I have a 2 hour flexibility and if it exceeds 2 hours then i have to reject it. I am set in EST, but i want to do the check based on GMT only so that there is no errors in the time difference. How can i set to GMT in my php code and how do i check for the 2 hours flexible time difference? like for this example it is acceptable for any time between `11-01-2010 18:48:25` and `11-01-2010 22:48:25`. Also will it be an issue if $date_time is `11-01-2010 23:48:23`?

**Clarification**

I am doing a `$date_time=$_GET['date_time'];`. Then i need to check if this new $date_time if within 2 hours range of the current GMT time. if it is in the range, then i will proceed to execute that code, else i will show an error or do something else. I wanted to know how i am going to check this 2 hours range for this $date_time variable.

Comment: I don't really got this question. Are you asking for adding two hours to the time()?

Comment: Hope i made it more clear now.

Comment: What format is `11-01-2010` in - mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way how to convert your time format into a [**UNIX timestamp**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_timestamp):

```
$date = strptime($date_time, "%m-%d-%Y %T");
$ut = mktime($date['tm_hour'], $date['tm_min'], $date['tm_sec'], 1 + $date['tm_mon'], $date['tm_mday'], 1900 + $date['tm_year']);

$now = time();

if($ut >= $now && $ut <= ($now + 7200)) { // 7200 = 2 * 60 * 60 seconds
    // allowed
}
```

Reference: [`strptime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php), [`mktime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php), [`time`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php).

**Note:** `time()` always returns the UNIX timestamp in UTC (regardless of time settings). So this assumes that the `$date_time` timestamp **is** a GMT time.

[**Working example**](http://codepad.org/gpkVxPiF) (of course you have to provide a valid GMT time for `$date_time`).

**Note 2:** If the input time is not in GMT, you can set the timezone with [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) (affects `mktime` but not `time`).

[**Working example**](http://codepad.org/zdnyriBV) (change time and timezone accordingly)

Answer (score 1):

If you run on PHP > 5.3, you can use DateTime for this :

```
$my_date = "11-01-2010 20:48:25";

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y H:i:s', $my_date);
$date_lower = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y H:i:s', $my_date);
$date_upper = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y H:i:s', $my_date);
$date_lower->sub(new DateInterval('PT2H'));
$date_upper->add(new DateInterval('PT2H'));

var_dump($date >= $date_lower && $date <= $date_upper); // bool(true)
```

I find it more readable.

You can also use another timezone if necessary, check the third argument of createFromFormat.

Comment: I am using php 5.2.14. I should have mentioned. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

If PHP >= 5.3 (you've got a seriously weird format BTW):

```
date_default_timezone_set('EST');
$inputtime = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y H:i:s','11-01-2010 20:48:25',new DateTimeZone("GMT"));
$diff = $inputtime->getTimestamp() - time();
if(abs($diff) > 7200){
    //more then 2 hours difference.
}
```

Comment: I am using php 5.2.14. I should have mentioned. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to never pass times and dates with format string. Just convert it later. You just pass the timestamp as a get variable and then you format it in the script.
It's the best solution and also the cleanest.

Then use the following code:

```
$flexibility = X seconds;
if ($date_time < time() - $flexibility or $date_time > time() + $flexibility)
{ /*Error*/ }
```